# Wildcard search in Word OfficeJS for Office 2016 and WordOnline not working

Tags: office-js

I'm trying to write a Word Addin that needs to do a wildcard search. Unfortunately using `{matchWildcards: true}` in `context.document.body.search(SEARCHSTRING, {matchWildcards: true}` fails.

I'm using Word Online and Word 2016 (16.0.4266.1001, 32-bit). Wildcard searches fail in both.

I think this ought to work:

If the text `toon` is in a new docx document, it should get matched by:

```
click = async () = {
    return Word.run(async context => {
        searchResults = context.document.body.search('to*n', {matchWildcards: true})
        context.load(searchResults, 'text')
        await context.sync()
        console.log("len search results: " + searchResults.items.length);
        // should be > 0, but its not.
    }
}
```

Is this an issue with WordOnline or this version of Word 2016? Do I need to initialize SearchOptions in some other way?

**Edit**: A bit of additional info.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/word-api-requirement-sets says :
"The build number for Office 2016 installed via MSI is 16.0.4266.1001. This version only contains the WordApi 1.1 requirement set."

And matchWildcards is listed as part of the WordApi 1.1 set - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.searchoptions?view=office-js.

So it doesn't look like there should be a version problem, right?

Comment: Just to be sure I understand, have you found that the code **does** work for Office 365 Word (non-MSI)?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't test under office 365 (desktop) word. The MSI and Word Online are the only version's I've got.

Comment: Your code works for me in Word Online. Maybe the problem is that you seem to be mixing "callback" syntax and "await" syntax. What happens if you replace the "return" in front of Word.run with "await"?

Comment: Huh. I was able to get it working in Word Online too - there must be some typo in my real code that I didn't make it the example above. The same addin doesn't work for the MSI Word that I have though. I guess that must be some version thing, with the MSI Word not being fully supported for officejs. Darn.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: I should clarify that when I got your code to work it was only after I replaced the "return" in front of Word.run with "await".

Answer (score 0):

The property should be set as `matchWildCards` (capital `W` and `C`, even though the documentation uses `matchWildcards`).